# Wordpress and woocommerce checkbox not visible

Tags: wordpress, checkbox, woocommerce, themes, checkout

I use Wordpress and woocommerce https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce/

And businessx theme https://wordpress.org/themes/businessx/

My problem is the checkbox are not visible and i need to show the checkbox

I add an image to show the problem

What solution i can use to solve this problem and have a normal checkbox ?

If i change theme the problem is solved but i use this theme for my site and i need checkbox visible, I try from 10 days to solve this problem without success.

This is the site with bug: hotelfucsia.altervista.org/?product=test

Add a product in cart and after submit and go in checkout page under payment zone you see the terms with missing checkbox.

It'a a probablu a css bug but i don't know what file edit.

[image]

Comment: The theme style may be hiding your checkbox. if you can give the url of the page, we can debug the issue

Comment: Hi @melvin thanks for help this is the site hotelfucsia.altervista.org/?product=test add product in cart and submit order, after payment selection you can see the terms with missing checkbox. I found another site that use the same wordpress theme and solved the checkbox terms error this site solved the problem imperiumgames.co.za/shop/ add in cart a product, and go in checkout page to see the terms checkbox fixed that works. I think this is a css problem but I do not know what css file edit. thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this bug need a custom css i found it in the forum or creatore of plugin

Add in custom css this custom code to fix all checkbox missing of businessx theme

```
/* Enter your customs CSS here */

.woocommerce form .form-row .input-checkbox {
display: inline-block;
margin: -2px 8px 0 0;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

.post-single {
font-size: 1.5em !important;
}
}

.wpcf7 input.wpcf7-text { width: 50%; }
.wpcf7 textarea.wpcf7-textarea { width: 50%; }
.wpcf7-form textarea { height: 200px; }

.wpcf7-form-control-wrap input { border: 1px solid rgba(154, 141, 141, 0.86) !important;}
.wpcf7-form-control-wrap textarea { border: 1px solid rgba(154, 141, 141, 0.86) !important;}
```